# evaluate a post - loaded script

Tags: javascript, html, eval

i have a String in html which should is post loaded in body.

```
    var str = new String("<span>Hello</span><script>window.alert('hello');</script>");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML=str;
```

but the alert does not come. so i added this:

```
    for(i=0;scr=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('script')[i];i++) {
    eval(src.innerHTML);
    };
```

but even it doesn't work. can u solve my problem?

Comment: Where did `src` come from? And where did `scr` come from?

Comment: With the first solution, did the word `hello` end up on the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML="<span>Hello</span><script>window.alert('hello');<\/script>";
var alert_func = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML
if(alert_func.indexOf("alert") != -1) {
  eval(alert_func);
}
```

This code will first set the innerHTML of the `<body>` tags to `<span>Hello</span><script>window.alert('hello');</script>`. Then a variable `alert_func` will store the content between the `<script>` tags. If there is the word "alert" in `alert_func`, we will evaluate whatever is between the `<script>` tags and give the alert.

Comment: Can you also explain why this is supposed to work? Just dumping some lines of code isn't very helpful.